# Linked List - How a single object is storing so many addresses one after other?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I learn about data structures and Linked Lists and I don't understand something. How can a single object store so many addresses and datas. When I learned about object I saw that you need to create new objects if you want to store many datas for a single variable, but now at Linked List, the newNode object will store data1,next1, data2, next2,.... datan, nextn.

When the program runs list.insert(11) and data become 11, why the old data which is 5 is not deleted?

Sorry for my english grammar, and any feedback will be apreciated. Thank you!

The following code is about nodes inserting in a linked list:

**Node class**:

```
public class Node {

    int data;
    Node next;

    public int getData() {

        return data;
    }

    public Node getNext() {

        return next;
    }

    public void setData(int data) {

        this.data = data;
    }

    public void setNext(Node next) {

        this.next = next;
    }

}
```

**MyLinkedList class:**

```
public class MyLinkedList {

    Node head;

    public void insert(int data) {

        Node newNode = new Node();
        newNode.setData(data); 
        newNode.setNext(null);

        if (head == null) {

            head = newNode;
        }
        else {

            Node n = head;
            while(n.getNext() != null) {

                n = n.getNext();
            }

            n.setNext(newNode);
        }
    }

    public void show() {

        Node newNode = head;
        while (newNode.getNext() != null) {

            System.out.println(newNode.getData());
            newNode = newNode.getNext();
        }

        System.out.println(newNode.getData());
    }

}
```

**Runnner class:**

```
public class Runner {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        MyLinkedList list = new MyLinkedList();

        list.insert(5);
        list.insert(11);
        list.insert(9);
        list.insert(3);
        list.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: No. A Node contains a single data element. But it has a reference to another node, which contains another single data element and which also has a reference to another node. Just a "elvis" refers to you, and to you only. But if I ask you "who is your father", then you'll be able to tell me "elvis senior". And I can then ask elvis senior "who is your father", and he will answer "john bar", etc. The person "elvis" is a single person, but through this person, by asking repeatedly for the father (or the mother, or the neighbours, etc.), I can get access to many other persons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked list itself almost knows nothing about the data it contains. It usually only holds a variable for the total **size** and a reference to the first node, the **head** (and to the tail too in a doubly linked list).

A node is an own object which holds a **data** variable and a reference to the **next node**, which again is an own object and so on. (In a doubly linked list nodes also have pointer to the previous node)

[image]

So in order to access the fifth node you would need to start at the head and follow the next pointers up to the fifth node. There is no direct access in linked lists. However, it allows to easily insert or remove elements by just re-arranging the next pointers of nodes, like skipping a node for example.

[image]

Also, note that there is **no limit** on how much data one object can hold. You totally could hold all data at once in one object. Also variables of an object are only references to where the real data is stored. So it doesn't need to be next to each other in the memory, it can be scattered around all over the place.

An array on the contrary has all data connected in the memory. That is why direct access works well with arrays. You have the base address where the array starts, know the byte size of the elements and can by that easily compute where in the memory data for which element starts:

```
// Memory address of fifth element of an int[] array
base + 4 * sizeof(int)
```

That's also why they need to be of fixed size.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: Isn't the old node deleted when the new node is created? I thought that there is a single object that store data1, next1, then when the data2, next 2 is created the old data1, next1 is deleted.

Comment: When the object Node3 is created the object Node2 isn't deleted (by Grbage Collection) because the Node1 is pointing at it. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: You have one node object for every data item. The `LinkedList` objects only purpose is to hold a reference to the first node object and meta data. Deletion of nodes works implicitly by just skipping (see the image). The garbage collector will then eventually delete the skipped node since nobody refers to it anymore. The garbage collector only deletes objects that are not referenced anymore. So as long as every node is referenced by something they won't be deleted.